# The web.config file for this project is missing the required DirectRequestModule

Tags: asp.net, extjs, web-config, ext.net

Having put ResourceManager and Window component on a web app I'm debugging asp.net app but 
it shows Warning message!

```
The web.config file for this project is missing the required DirectRequestModule.

Example

<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="DirectRequestModule" type="Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule, Ext.Net" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
More information available at "Getting Started".
```

How to fix this kind of error ?

Comment: added this   `<httpHandlers>
   <add path="*/ext.axd" verb="*" type="Ext.Net.ResourceHandler" validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
   <add name="DirectRequestModule" type="Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule, Ext.Net" />
  </httpModules>
  <pages>
   <controls>
    <add assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagPrefix="ext" />
   </controls>
  </pages>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `README.txt` contains a `Web.config` sample, see

http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Introduction/README/

As well, installing Ext.NET via NuGet will setup the correct Web.config nodes automatically.

```
install-package ext.net
```

Hope this helps

Comment: absolutely what I did the first one !

Answer (score 0):

A bit strange, the way I fixed this..

Earlier i was using Server.Transfer(..) to redirect the page
then I started facing the same problem

Then I searched  a lot and in the end I changed that Server.Transfer(..) to Response.Redirect(..), And ta-da it worked perfectly..

Hope this helps you :-)